# Is there a way to put Setter elements inside EventTrigger?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, xaml

Working on a WPF application, I started working on a custom **ControlTemplate**. I reached the point where I need to change some control properties when an event occurs.

For this purpose, there are Setter elements. Seems all good, but I cannot use them inside **EventTrigger** elements. For example, if a simple **Trigger**, that can be bound to control properties, is used then **Setter** elements can be used inside. However, I do not want to bind to a property change but rather to an event.

Is there a way to do this in pure XAML or will I have to work in the code-behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put a `StoryBoard` there, and have it start an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` that will "animate" your properties instantly to the target state. If your properties are `double` or `Color` - even better: you will be able to actually make them transition smoothly using `DoubleAnimation` or `ColorAnimation` respectively.

I think this is a bit of an overkill, but if you want to use pure XAML, this is possible to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. With small modifications, I was able to change the property based on the event triggered. Just set the animation duration to 0 and KeyTime to 0 for the DiscreteObjectKeyFrame that was inside ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.